# Buffer overflow exploit works with gdb but not without

Tags: buffer-overflow, exploit-development

I am learning about buffer overflows and I’m developing my very first exploit.

There is a server process that listens to a socket and forks a new process for each client. The child process has a buffer overflow vulnerability which I’m exploiting.

My exploit works if I start the server using gdb, however I get a segfault when the exploit code is run if I simply start the server with no gdb.

My question is - does gdb automatically deactivate some protection mechanisms, like aslr/stack protection etc? What would be a possible explanation of this behaviour?

I have compiled the server with -zexecstack -fno-stack-protector , I still can’t exploit it without gdb.

This is on debian x86. 
By running the server with gdb I mean I run ‚gdb server‘ and then just type ‚run‘ in the gdb console, no breakpoints or anything else. This way my exploit is successful (makes a curl request to my server)

Comment: Stack frame address during debugging may be different from address during normal execution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17775966

Comment: @MichalK yes that seems to be the case, thanks for the hint! Indeed the return address is different if I start with gdb or if I attach gdb at a later point.
The return address I obtain when attaching gdb after start is the one that works if I leave gdb completely out. 
Please make this an answer instead of a comment so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

GDB uses a debugging hooks + it's intended to use a debug symbols and handle them, and it alters actual behaviour. So - it's clear that some artifacts will show up for sure

Answer (score 0):

Per [codeblog](https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2010/07/03/gdb-turns-off-aslr/comment-page-1/):

> Starting with GDB version 7, first appearing in Ubuntu with Karmic (Ubuntu 9.10), ASLR is turned off (via the ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE personality flag) for the debugged process. If you want a more realistic view of how a process will appear in memory, you must “set disable-randomization off” in gdb.

Comment: This only partially answers the OPs question, about why his exploit doesn't work. Also, it's copy pasta.